# Sound not playing when iPhone is in silent mode

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, audio

I am making an app that needs to play sounds even if the iPhone is in silent mode, but with the code I have now (look at bottom of this post) it wont't play sounds if the iPhone is in silent mode.

I am using the following code:

Viewcontroller.h:

```
@interface SoundViewController : UIViewController <UICollectionViewDataSource, UIApplicationDelegate, AVAudioPlayerDelegate, ADBannerViewDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate> {
    SystemSoundID SoundID;
    NSString *listPath;

}
```

ViewController.m:

```
CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (__bridge CFStringRef) [mainArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row], CFSTR("wav"), NULL);
UInt32 soundID;
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way you are triggering sounds using **AudioServicesPlaySystemSound** will ALWAYS obey the ringer/silent switch.

To play sound when the device is set to silent you need to use another way such as **AVAudioPlayer** class.

Comment: Linking to some documentation with a basic example would be an ideal addition to this answer.